# Why is the looping call required when consuming from queue?

Tags: rabbitmq, twisted, pika, python-pika

I am trying to consume from rabbit queues using pika and twisted:

1. Constantly (new message -> consume)
2. Once (new message -> consume once, don't consume again until I say so)

The only input I have is this [example](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.2/examples/twisted_example.html). It covers use case 1. What about use case 2?

Isn't `basic_consume` implemented in a way that it will "notify" when a new message is ready? Why is it my "job" to start the looping call? It seems that polling is against the event loop pattern in twisted, no?

*When making a http request with twisted, it sends off the request and continues the execution (through deferreds) once it comes back. Why does that not work in RabbitMQ/pika?*

Here is how I would expect it to work:

1. subscribe to queue
2. consume from queue (doesn't fire immediately unless there is a message in the queue, will fire every time when there is a new message in the queue, I am ignoring *qos* for now.)

How do I consume a single message, e.g. `basic_get`? Do I need to start the looping call, and once I received the message, stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're asking several questions so I'll try to answer them all. I'm one of Pika's maintainers but am not as familiar with Twisted as the other connection adapters.

> Isn't basic_consume implemented in a way that it will "notify" when a new message is ready? Why is it my "job" to start the looping call? It seems that polling is against the event loop pattern in twisted, no?

[Twisted's documentation for `LoopingCall`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/8.1.0/api/twisted.internet.task.LoopingCall.html) states this:

> Call a function repeatedly. If f returns a deferred, rescheduling will not take place until the deferred has fired.

The [example code](https://pika.readthedocs.io/en/0.11.2/examples/twisted_example.html) uses `@defer.inlineCallbacks` and the `yield` statement to return deferred functions. So, `LoopingCall` will **not** call the function repeatedly, it will only schedule a new call after the deferreds fire.

> Here is how I would expect it to work... consume from queue (doesn't fire immediately unless there is a message in the queue, will fire every time when there is a new message in the queue, I am ignoring qos for now.)

This is exactly how the example code works.

> How do I consume a single message, e.g. `basic_get`? Do I need to start the looping call, and once I received the message, stop it?

If you set prefetch (QoS) to `1`, then RabbitMQ will only send one message to the consumer and will not send the next one until the first is acknowledged by `basic_ack`.